# Rotate icon 180 degree with animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, iconbutton

I have a `IconButton`, Normally, It's icon is `Icons.expand_more` but When I press that its icon should be `Icons.expand_less`. I want to animated this so that if I press that button, it will rotate and point the downwords from upwords. and same when I press the `expand_less` then it should become `expand_more` with rotating animation. How can I acheive this ?
below is my code :

```
    IconButton(
      icon:  _expanded ? Icon(Icons.expand_less) : Icon(Icons.expand_more),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
           _expanded = !_expanded;
        });
      },
   )
```

I tried to use animatedContainer but it didn't work as I am using two different icons and that rotation effect I cannot acheive with this.
I also tried to rotate the icon with below approach but it cannot show the animation when it is rotating from 0 to 180 degree.

```
IconButton(
              icon: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                      angle: _expanded ? 0 : 180 * math.pi / 180,
                      child: Icon(Icons.expand_less))),
              // icon:
              //     _expanded ? Icon(Icons.expand_less) : Icon(Icons.expand_more),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _expanded = !_expanded;
                });
              },
            )
```

This is before expansion :

> [image: before expansion]

This is after expansion :

> [image: after expansion]

*I want the rotation animation on button click.*

Comment: Thanks all for the answers!
I posted the full solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68175950/14343554).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: achieved Animation]

Thanks to @krumpli.

1. Define `AnimationController _controller`.
2. Define `init` method as :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      upperBound: 0.5,
    );
  }
```

3. Define `dispose` method as :

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
```

4. With the use of the widget `RotationTransition` :

```
RotationTransition(
              turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.expand_less),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_expanded) {
                      _controller..reverse(from: 0.5);
                    } else {
                      _controller..forward(from: 0.0);
                    }
                    _expanded = !_expanded;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
```

**Don't forget to add** `with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` **in the class defintion.**

Comment: Do you have and idea how to do it if you have a draggable body? Your solution works if I press the button (the button opens the bottom panel) , but If I drag the panel, the icon won't rotate when the panel is fully open. Same when closing, it works when pressed, it doesn't when it's dragged

Comment: Good work.  There are a few places for improvement though.  You don't need to use the `..` cascade operator in your call to `setState` since nothing is being returned.  In your `dispose` method, `super.dispose` should be call after the controller is disposed, not before.  Lastly, your icons are backwards.  The down chevron (equivalent to the `expand_more` icon) should be visible in the collapsed state, and the up chevron (equivalent to the `expand_less` icon) should be visible in the expanded state.  This way the icons indicate the action that will take place when pressed.

Comment: One additional observation/recommendation.  If you change `reverse(from: 0.5)` to `1.0` you can remove `upperBound` entirely and set the `end: 0.5` when you create your `Tween` object.  This will allow the same `AnimationController` to be reused for full animations (not just half) on different objects in the same widget.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [test sample](https://dartpad.dev/13d6b7206ec19824b63a7c1c658890da?null_safety=true) I have made for what you need.

This also applies a curve which is a good Flutter suggestion.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RotateIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  const RotateIcon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RotateIconState createState() => _RotateIconState();
}

class _RotateIconState extends State<RotateIcon>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;
  late final Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    _animation =
        Tween(begin: 0.0, end: .5).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              RotationTransition(
                turns: _animation,
                child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_controller.isDismissed) {
                      _controller.forward();
                    } else {
                      _controller.reverse();
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text("Animate"))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, I'm glad my answer was good enough. You can now customize it with your code and change the times for the animation

Comment: I figured out the solution from @krumpli's answer but after watching your solution( )  I confirmed that !

Comment: OK I have updated the answer to add the important code which is the entire class. Is that better?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Add an animation controller: `AnimationController _animationController:`

```
initState() {
    _animationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    }
```

wrap your icon in this:

```
RotationTransition(
         turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                .animate(_animationController),
         child: IconButton(icon: //YOUR ICON),
         onPressed: () {
             setState(() {
        _animationController1.forward(from: 0.0);
      });
     },
   ),
 )
```

Finally:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController?.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: thanks mate! Your solution does the job of rotating animation but I needed specific rotation animation on expanding and collapsing, which I figured out from your solution though.

Comment: Yepp, simple fix with a flag. Happy to help!